# nodeJS handling a <SELECT> tag doesn't register to sql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

all my other inputs are registering to my database, but for the input with  tag, it doesn't return a value nor a null.

my code:

```
<Select name="role"options={role}
placeholder="Select Role"
className="role-select"
theme={customTheme}
isClearable
styles={stylesSelect}
onClick={(e)=>{
setRoleReg(e.target.value);
}}/>


 const role = [
        {value: 'super-admin', label:'Super Admin'},
        {value: 'admin', label:'Admin'},
        {value: 'internal-user', label:'User'},
    ];
```

and my server looks like this:

```
app.post('/addnewuser', (req,res)=>{

    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password
    const role = req.body.role
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds,(err, hash)=>{

    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, role)VALUES (?,?,?)",
    [username, hash, role], 
    (err, result)=>{
        console.log(role)
        console.log(err);
        }   
    );
})
})
```

Comment: Try changing the `onClick` event of the `Select` element to `onChange`.

Comment: yup tried this, but the values are not showing in the front end